# operação com data sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, oracle, datetime

Senhores, estou migrando o meu sistema de Oracle para SQL Server,

estou com problemas para fazer a seguinte operação

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN - EPL.DAT_FABRICA) > 0
      THEN CAST(((CAST(SYSDATE-EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS INT)) /
        (CAST(EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN-EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS INT)) * 100) AS INT)
      ELSE 0
    END AS PERCENTUAL_P,
    epl.*
FROM emp_produto_lotacao EPL
```

esta query retorna os valores corretamente no Oracle. Porem no SQLServer os valores vem zerados. Lembrando que no SQLServer o `SYSDATE` deve ser substituído por `GETDATE()`

Comment: a conversão para int pode estar retornando um valor menor que zero, tentou converter para float usando `convert(float, SYSDATE-EPL.DAT_FABRICA)` para fazer o cálculo?

Comment: tentei usar convert também, acho que deve dar certo também, a dica de alterar pra float foi que me ajudou.
Obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ivan, para calcular diferença entre datas, utilize a função [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189794.aspx).

A respeito do cálculo de percentual, atento que, em T-SQL, o operador **/** possui comportamento variável, podendo ser divisão inteira ou divisão real (ponto flutuante), dependendo das características dos operandos.
Por exemplo:

```
  1 / 2 = 0
  1.0 / 2 = 0.5
```

Por isso, sugiro que no cálculo do percentual implemente algo como

```
  (Cast( dividendo as float) / divisor) as Percentual
```

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

A sintaxe correspondente no `SQL SERVER`  para o trecho `CAST(((CAST(SYSDATE-EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS INT))` é `DATEDIFF(day, getdate() , EPL.DAT_FABRICA)`

Sua query ficaria assim.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(day, EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN , EPL.DAT_FABRICA)) > 0
      THEN (DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), EPL.DAT_FABRICA)) 
      / (DATEDIFF(day, EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN , EPL.DAT_FABRICA) * 100)
      ELSE 0
    END AS PERCENTUAL_P,
    epl.*
FROM emp_produto_lotacao EPL
```

Comment: CASE WHEN (cast(EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN - EPL.DAT_FABRICA as float)) > 0
      THEN CAST((( CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) - CAST(EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS FLOAT)) /
        (CAST(EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN AS FLOAT) - CAST(EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS FLOAT)) * 100) AS INT)
      ELSE 10
END AS PERCENTUAL_P,

Comment: Olá Dragon Ball,

Comment: Eu tentei com o Datediff, e ele sempre cai no else, alterei pra 10 o else , e só retorna 10.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde senhores,

Obrigado por Ajudarem,

Consegui resolver a questão do Percentual da seguinte maneira:

```
       CASE WHEN (cast(EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN - EPL.DAT_FABRICA as float)) > 0
            THEN CAST((( CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT) - CAST(EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS FLOAT))
                 /  (CAST(EPL.DAT_VENCIMEN AS FLOAT) - CAST(EPL.DAT_FABRICA AS FLOAT)) * 100) AS  INT) 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS PERCENTUAL_P, –
```